# Distance between passing planets for atmosphere exchange to occur

Tags: planets, physics, astronomy, atmosphere, rogue-planets

If a rogue planet (let's say about as big as the Earth) flew by the Earth, how close would it need to pass to planet Earth for atmosphere to be exchanged between the two planets?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Samwise*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Is it already established that a rogue planet as big as earth can travel through the solar system and get that close to the sun?

Comment: @Raditz_35 Of course - what would be the reason it couldn't?

Comment: The rogue planet's speed would be a problem.  Too much and the friction of passage would make the two atmospheres burn.  And I'd hate to think about the tides.  Oh, the tides....

Comment: @RadovanGarabík Jupiter for a start.

Answer (score 0):

How much atmosphere do you want to switch? You could get a few atoms going between them if they passed no closer than Lunar Orbit, if you want a bulk exchange that would be visible on the surface when it occurred you could be in big trouble with the [Roche Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit) of your rogue, or the Earth for that matter. Even if one planet or the other wasn't actually shredded the tidal forces would make a nuclear war look survivable for our civilisation.